# Почему возникает ошибка TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

В данном примере (вычисление простых чисел https://habrahabr.ru/post/122538/):

```
n = input()
lst=[2]
for i in range(3, n+1, 2):
    if (i > 10) and (i%10==5):
        continue
    for j in lst:
        if j*j-1 > i:
            lst.append(i)
            break
        if (i % j == 0):
            break
    else:
        lst.append(i)
print (lst)
```

возникает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:/Users/E/Documents/code/Python/Edu/spojcom/Prime.py", line 4, in <module>
for i in range(3, int(n+1), 2):  
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

видимо, не нравится `n+1`?!
писал так: `int(n+1)` но, также, безрезультатно.
Что поправить?

Comment: не относится напрямую к вопросу, но [Решето Эратосфена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0) является более простым и эффективным алгоритмом, по сравнению с делением в слепую, если нужно найти все простые числа меньше заданного числа. Вот [пример реализации на Питоне](http://stackoverflow.com/a/193605/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вводится от пользователя строка, помещается в n и вы пытаетесь сделать n+1, то есть сложить строку и число. Вот и ошибка.
`int(n) + 1` должно решить проблему.

Comment: Спасибо, решение подошло. Не так давно изучаю Python, делал так: int(n+1)

Comment: Сначала преобразование к числу, потом сложение. Подошедший ответ можете отметить решением при помощи "галочки".

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка возникает потому что код, написанный для Питона 2, вы исполняете на Питоне 3: `input()` на Питоне 3 ведёт себя как `raw_input()` из Питона 2 — введённая строка возвращается как есть (без `eval()`). На Питоне 2, `input()` равнозначен `eval(raw_input())` и поэтому если пользователь ввёл строку `1`, то она преобразуется в целое число (`int`) автоматически.

На Питоне 3 нужно писать: `n = int(input("Введите целое число: "))` вместо `n = input()`, то есть необходимо явно преобразовывать ввод из строки в нужный тип (`int` в данном случае) — и даже в Питоне 2, следовало бы писать `n = int(raw_input())` вместо `n = input()`, чтобы запретить произвольный код, такой как `__import__('os').remove('важный файл')`.

Без явного `int`, позже в программе возникает ошибка, упомянутая в вопросе, при попытке использовать строку как целое число, например:

```
>>> "1" + 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

В некоторый языках неявные преобразования разрешены, например, `"1" + 1` равно `"11"` в Javascript и `say "1" + 1` печатает `2` в Perl. Опыт показал, что вред от подобных неявных преобразований превышает пользу от возможного небольшого удобства использования — тяжелее понять какой результат ожидается, что ухудшает читаемость и увеличивает вероятность скрытых багов.

В Питоне неявные преобразования из строки в число (и обратно) запрещены. Строка (объект `str`) всегда остаётся строкой. Если нужно целое число, то необходимо явно вызвать `int()`, чтобы создать новый объект с типом `int`.